# Have Consul auto-start on launch with macOS

Tags: macos, consul, autostart

I've just started looking into using Consul and was following the [consul-devops-handbook](https://www.gitbook.com/book/imaginea/consul-devops-handbook/details). It had some details on [auto-starting Consul](https://imaginea.gitbooks.io/consul-devops-handbook/content/auto_start.html), however this was only for Ubuntu.

Is it possible someone has a guide for achieving this for macOS?

With macOS I'm imagining it has something to do with adding it to LaunchDaemon perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can achieve this by adding a `.plist` file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>consul</string>
                <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                <array>
                        <string>/usr/local/bin/consul</string>
                        <string>agent</string>
                        <string>-config-dir</string>
                        <string>/etc/consul.d/client</string>
                </array>
                <key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>
                <key>KeepAlive</key><true/>

                <key>StandardOutPath</key>
                <string>/var/log/consul.log</string>
                <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
                <string>/var/log/consul_err.log</string>

        </dict>
</plist>
```